# How should I notate this chord?

Tags: chords, notation, jazz

This small dilemma I'm having right now is dealing with a problem many jazz musicians face: chord notation. The notes in the chord (in ascending order) are as follows:

C Eb(D#) F Ab(G#) Bb

Would I write this as something like Cmin11(b13) or C+min11

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this chord appear within a larger context of a piece of music? You consider this a C of some sort, and the first answer here recommends looking at it as an F of some sort—others here may know something I don’t, but if this chord appears around other chords (and you’re not talking simply about a chord in complete musical isolation), knowing them might be helpful.

Comment: This is completely isolated

Comment: Side remark : the chord notes are a pentatonic scale (based on Ab major pentatonic) Ab Bb C Eb F

Answer (score 5):

As you have a full Fm triad in there (F, Ab, C), and in fact a full Fm7 chord (F, Ab, C, Eb), it may be easier to think of F as the root and therefore interpret this as a Fm7add11/C, in other words Fm7add11 in second inversion. Often chords are simpler to name when you don't consider the bass note to be the root. I suppose it depends partly upon how strongly you feel the C bass note to be the root of this chord.

Comment: I agree with this and would add that what is most recognizable is best. An Fm7add11 is going to be more quickly processed by a player than a C+m11 or Cmin11b13.  You do not have an actual C+ triad because of the Eb and trying to work around all the exceptions takes too much thought.

Answer (score 2):

How should I notate this chord?

"chords" are usually composed of thirds. in your example, C Eb(D#) F Ab(G#) Bb, my ear hears this as a Bb chord, as follows:

Bb, (d), F, Ab, C, Eb, so its essentially an 11th chord in 5th inversion. If you want to give it a name, I would spell it out just as the example shows (C, Eb, F Ab and Bb). The names of tall tertial harmonies are so subjective that two performers will play the chord differently, unless it is spelled out.

Comment: Or even better: Fm7/Bb

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might consider is **Ab69/C**. When you want to be that specific with what pitches are being played finding the simplest spelling can be your best bet. That being said, no matter how the chord is spelled there's no guarantee these exact pitches will be played by the performer.